# Quasar: Remove parameter from default manifest

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, quasar-framework, manifest.json

On my vue.js PWA, there's a manifest.json generated by Quasar.

From what I understand, the manifest generated by Quasar uses the parameters from my `quasar.conf.js` file:

```
manifest: {
        name: `App name`,
        short_name: `app short name`,
        description: `Application description`,
        display: 'fullscreen',
        orientation: 'any',
        background_color: '#ffffff',
        theme_color: '#000000',
        icons: [...]
}
```

The resulting compiled manifest looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "App name",
    "short_name": "app short name",
    "description": "Application description",
    "display": "fullscreen",
    "start_url": ".",
    "orientation": "any",
    "background_color": "#ffffff",
    "theme_color": "#000000",
    "icons": [...],
}
```

What I want to do now is to remove a parameter completely from the default manifest. Specifically, I want the parameter `start_url` not to show up on my compiled manifest. I can modify its value by modifying this parameter on the `quasar.conf.js` but I cannot completely remove it. It will always be added with the default value `"start_url": "."`.

Any hints how to completely remove `start_url` from the compiled manifest?

**Update:**

**quasar.conf.js**

```
const open = require('open')
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin')
const { configure } = require('quasar/wrappers')
module.exports = configure(function (ctx) {
  return {
     pwa: {
      workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest', // 'GenerateSW' or 'InjectManifest',
      workboxOptions: {
        exclude: [
         /^.*php\/.*$/,
        ]
      },
      // for the custom service worker ONLY (/src-pwa/custom-service-worker.[js|ts])
      // if using workbox in InjectManifest mode
      chainWebpackCustomSW (chain) {
       chain.plugin('eslint-webpack-plugin')
       .use(ESLintPlugin, [{ extensions: ['js'] }])
      },
      manifest: {
        name: `App name`,
        short_name: `app short name`,
        description: `Application description`,
        display: 'fullscreen',
        orientation: 'any',
        background_color: '#ffffff',
        theme_color: '#000000',
        icons: [
          {
            src: 'icons/icon-128x128.png',
            sizes: '128x128',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: 'icons/icon-192x192.png',
            sizes: '192x192',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: 'icons/icon-256x256.png',
            sizes: '256x256',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: 'icons/icon-384x384.png',
            sizes: '384x384',
            type: 'image/png'
          },
          {
            src: 'icons/icon-512x512.png',
            sizes: '512x512',
            type: 'image/png'
          }
        ]
      },
      extendManifestJson(json) {
        delete json.start_url;
      },
    },
    cordova: {
      // noIosLegacyBuildFlag: true, // uncomment only if you know what you are doing
    },
    // Full list of options: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-capacitor-apps/configuring-capacitor
    capacitor: {
      hideSplashscreen: true
    },
    // Full list of options: https://v2.quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-electron-apps/configuring-electron
    electron: {
      bundler: 'packager', // 'packager' or 'builder',
      ...
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I used a workaround to solve this: add a manifest.json file with adjusted parameters on the application root without using quasar.conf.js for this.

Comment: Since the static manifest is not very helpful for other configuration reasons (other, actually dynamic manifest entries), a solution for the dynamic, quasar-generated manifest would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

The `extendManifestJson` function in quasar.config.js lets us tamper with the manifest json object allowing us to use the [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator on any unwanted properties.

**quasar.config.js**

```js
pwa: {
  extendManifestJson(json) {
    delete json.start_url;
  }
},
```

Comment: That could be a good solution. Does this work together with 'InjectManifest' option for the workboxPluginMode? https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-pwa/configuring-pwa shows a sample with GenerateSW and in my test it does not seem to completely remove the parameter.

Comment: can you post your config?  I tested both workboxModes and it worked ok but all other configs I used were default

Comment: I have extended the above description with a more complete snippet from my quasar.conf.js. Does that help? I seem to be running on quasar v2.7.7, @quasar/app v3.3.3, maybe that also makes a difference. I had tried also to leave the previous `manifest` section away, which produces errors and also to add an additional manifest.json to src-pwa to be used with `extendManifestJson`. Neither seemed to pick up the delete command.

Comment: could you post a sample of your test with the InjectManifest workboxMode?